# Excel - Turn rows into columns with data

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet with values

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
 1    A    B    C
 2    A    B    C
 3    A    B    C
```

How can I quickly change it so that it is in the form of:

```
Col1 Col2
 1    A
 1    B
 1    C
 2    A
 2    B
 2    C
 3    A
 3    B
 3    C
```

Doing it manually is not really an options as there is a lot of data

I am doing this so that I can make a csv and upload it to my MySQL database

Comment: if you have excel 2016 (or Excel 2013 with Power Query Addin), you can make it in Get & Transform with the [unpivot function](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Unpivot-columns-Power-Query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098)

Comment: If you are willing to use Powershell, you might like the answer given here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099216/powershell-expand-unpivot-all-entries-in-a-table-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **E1** enter:

```
=ROUNDUP(ROW()/3,0)
```

and copy down.  In **F1** enter:

```
=OFFSET($B$1,ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/3,0)-1,MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,3))
```

and copy down:

[image]